# Monotouch.Dialog Loading Overlay not showing

Tags: view, xamarin.ios, loading, monotouch.dialog

I am using the overlay code from here - http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message

It worked all fine..., I was able to call `View.Add(loadingOverlay)`

...until I changed things to MonoTouch.Dialog and it doesn't work anymore.

```
public partial class BaseView : UIViewController
{
    LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay;

    public void ProgressDialogShow(string message, string title)
    {
        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(message, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        View.Add(loadingOverlay);
    }
}
```

And the View itself (the LoginView) is inheriting from BaseView.

```
[Register("SecondLoginView")]
public class SecondLoginView : BaseView
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        root = new RootElement("Login") {
            new Section() {
            new EntryElement ("Benutzer", "Login", "Test")
            }
        };
        rootVC = new DialogViewController(root);
        nav = new UINavigationController(rootVC);
        window.RootViewController = nav;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
}
```

In that case, the Loadingoverlay is not showing up. How can I still use it with MonoTouch.Dialog?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack Shot is on the right track. The reason you are having issues is because you are structuring your application strangely. You should not have the `window.MakeKeyAndVisible` or `window.RootViewController` assignments in your `SecondLoginView` class.

You can add your `rootVC` as a subview like this:

V`iew.Add(rootVC.View);`

I am sure you can do it some way with the code you have, but the way I always use a `DialogViewController` (if its the only view meant to be on the screen) I inherit directly from it. If you want to provide some common overlay code, make your BaseView a `DialogViewController` and inherit that.

```
Something like: 

public partial class BaseDialogController : DialogViewController
{
    LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay;

    public void ProgressDialogShow(string message, string title)
    {
        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(message, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        View.Add(loadingOverlay);
    }
}
```

You should remove this code from the view controller:

```
    nav = new UINavigationController(rootVC);
    window.RootViewController = nav;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

If you want to make your controller in a `nav`, do it wherever you create SecondViewController. In your case, it might be in the storyboard file.

Answer (score 1):

In your second class "secondloginview" it seems like you are trying to do things that are typically done in the app delegate file.

In that code:

What you are doing is making a navigation controller into the root view controller for the app, and then setting the login window to the only view controller attached to that Nav controller.

I think what you want to do, is remove that navigation controller code and use this.PresentviewController(RootVC,true);

To display the dialog view controller for login.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you mean that. I removed the navigation controller code and used your proposal but still the same. The thing is, that when I don't call `window.MakeKeyAndVisible();` , it shows de loadingoverlay fine, but there is than a black background. But after calling `window.MakeKeyAndVisible();` its not shown, or its shown behind the "View".. I don't know how to place the LoadingOverlay after the `window.MakeKeyAndVisible();` call..